# Figure next to a list

Tags: floats, lists, tasks

I would like to place a figure next to a list, this the best I got. I have no idea how to do it.

```
\item Identify
    \begin{tasks}[counter-format =(tsk[1]), label-offset=1.25em](2)
         \task $f(-3)$ \, $f(2)$ $\lim f(x)$ 
         \includegraphics[width=150pt]{00.jpg}
    \end{tasks}
```

This is what I want to get [image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This sounds like a job for `minipage`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item One problem
\item Identify:\newline
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\linewidth}
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item $\displaystyle f(-2)$
    \item $\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow-2}f(x)$
    \item $\displaystyle f(0)$
    \item $\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow0}f(x)$
    \item $\displaystyle f(2)$
    \item $\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow2}f(x)$
    \item $\displaystyle f(x)$
    \item $\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow4}f(x)$
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \strut\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\newline\includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{example-image}
  \end{minipage}
\item Next problem
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: excelent, is there any way to get 2 columns? that's why I was using tasks

Comment: Do you mean two columns in the document or two columns of sub-tasks in one task? In the latter you can replace the image with a new set of sub-tasks. You need to change the enumeration counter by setting e.g. `\setcounter{enumii}{10}` before the first `\item`. You can of course have three minipages (two columns of sub-tasks and one image) next to each other, but it is starting to be crowded.