# Floating a graphic

Tags: floats

Need some help floating a graphic. I want the following graphic to float directly to the right of the enumeration below it. The enumeration should flow normally within the text (as if there was no picture there) and the picture's top should be roughly aligned with the top of the enumeration (the alignment is not *that* important). How do I do that?

**EDIT 1** 
Here's a working MWE

```
\documentclass[10pt,fleqn,reqno]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\setlist{topsep=0pt,itemsep=0pt,parsep=1\parsep,label={\textbf{\alph*})}}
\begin{document}

Region $\mathcal{R}$ is pictured below.

\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{sinhandcosh.PNG}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item $x=0$
    \item $x=2$
    \item $x=4$
    \item $x=-2$
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Here's a link to [the picture](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/wi0dnh05nj) (but I don't know how to load an attachment on here).

[image]

**EDIT 2**
Trying minipages (per suggestion in comments). It compiles, but puts the minipages vertically. Here's the minipages MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,fleqn,reqno]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\setlist{topsep=0pt,itemsep=0pt,parsep=1\parsep,label={\textbf{\alph*})}}
\begin{document}

Region $\mathcal{R}$ is pictured below.

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\linewidth}
    \begin{enumerate}
            \item $x=0$
            \item $x=2$
            \item $x=4$
            \item $x=-2$
    \end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{sinhandcosh.PNG}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem. While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Comment: Just a guess because I cannot test without a MWE, but I would probably place the enumeration and the image in two minipages besides each other.

Comment: There are tons of Q & A that show you how you can achieve such things. However, as pointed out by @samcarter, it is next-to-impossible to help you concretely as we do not know what document class you are using, nor do many users know what `\adjincludegraphics`, and we do not have your graphics file.

Comment: @samcarter (re: MWE) I'll try, but my preamble uses a "inputted" tex file.

Comment: @Jeff We don't need your complete document, just a compilable document that reproduces your problem.

Comment: So you want something like this? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/332843/figure-next-to-a-list

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Yes, but that example seems to require the minipages both be part of the same bullet item. I tried that, but have only one level of enumeration, and it put them minipages one above each other. I'll post what I tried to the question.

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice that there was a nested list in that example, but just ignore the outer list. If the minipages came one above the other, perhaps you had an empty line between them? Empty line = paragraph break. Edit: I see that's not the case.

Comment: @samcarter showed one possible solution. Note by the way if you replace the standard `\includegraphics` in your last code example with the `\adjincludegraphics[scale=0.3,valign=t]{../Workshops/src and sol/sinh and cosh.PNG}` you had in your original question, you'll get the alignment you're after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with two `minipage`s beside each other:

```
\documentclass[10pt,fleqn,reqno]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\setlist{topsep=0pt,itemsep=0pt,
  parsep=1\parsep,
    label={\textbf{\alph*})}}
\begin{document}

Region $\mathcal{R}$ is pictured below.

\bigskip

\noindent%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}%
\begin{enumerate}
    \item $x=0$
    \item $x=2$
    \item $x=4$
    \item $x=-2$
\end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}
\raisebox{\dimexpr-\height+\baselineskip}{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{DdkiH}}
\end{minipage}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Small tip: `\height` refers to the height of the box in `\raisebox`, so one could do something like `\raisebox{\dimexpr-\height+10pt}{...}`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thanks for the suggestion! I'm missing beamers columns environment where I could simply use `T` to top align the image :)