# How to have an image wrapped to a table

Tags: pdftex

I'm looking to do something like this in latex, I have tried different packages like wrap figure and wrap table but I can't seem to get it to work completely.

I want to do something similar to this.

[image]

So basically an image on a left and a table on a right that are both centered to each other.

I currently have the following code:

```
\begin{table}
\adjustimage{width=3cm,valign=c}{Illustrations/QFN-40-Backside}\quad%
\caption{Table for test} \label{fig:test}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
    Model & blurred \\
    $V_\mathrm{in}$ & blurred \\
    $V_\mathrm{out}$ & blurred \\
    $I_{\max}$ & blurred \\
\end{tabular}
```

\end{table}

Which is showing like this
[image]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/473242/36296 You can place image and table into two minipages besides each other

Comment: The problem is that \caption includes a \par at the beginning and end, putting the image, caption and tabular in separate paragraphs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see, if the following solution is acceptable to you:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{adjustbox}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
    \centering
\caption{Table for test} 
    \label{fig:test}
\begin{tabular}{cl}
\adjustimage{width=3cm,valign=c}{Illustrations/QFN-40-Backside}
    &   \begin{tabular}{@{} ll @{} }
        Model & blurred                 \\
        $V_\mathrm{in}$     & blurred   \\
        $V_\mathrm{out}$    & blurred   \\
        $I_{\max}$          & blurred 
        \end{tabular}
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you are welcome!. however, if answer work for you you can express your thankfulness with up voting answer (by clicking on up-pen at top left side of answer) or even accept it (by clicking on check mark at top left side of answer) :-)